# iOS 9.2 double touch fingerprint sensor

Tags: ios, iphone

I was messing around this morning and found that if I quickly double touch (NOT double-click) the fingerprint sensor on my iPhone 6S+ (iOS 9.2), the current app (or the home screen) slides down to the bottom half-screen, showing a blurred home screen background on the top half.  It doesn't matter if I use a finger that the sensor recognizes.  It goes back to normal after about 8 seconds or if you double-touch again, but I can't figure out what this mode is for??  Is this a bug or some hidden feature I haven't heard about yet?

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221155/what-gesture-is-triggered-by-wiggling-your-finger-on-the-home-button/221158#221158 & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201929/iphone-6-ios-8-is-my-multitasking-broken-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature!  It's so you can reach the upper part of the screen with you thumb.  It's called reachability, for more info [here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-reachability-on-iphone-6-6-plus/).

Comment: Strange.  If that was the intention, I would expect to be able to access the notifications pull-down too, but I can't.

Comment: Ahh--it looks like I can access it--I just have to be very accurate where I start the drag-down.  It can't start in the empty area.

Comment: Updated the answer.